# Multiples timer corriendo al mismo tiempo desde la misma funcion en distintos hilos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero usar una funcion para lanzar un timer con diferentes frecuencias para cada uno de los hilos que abro. No se si esto es posible. ¿Me podrian echar una mano?

```
import threading
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) 
lock = threading.Lock()

def f(freq):
    with lock:
        logger.info('f')
        threading.Timer(freq, f(freq)).start()
        print(freq)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='[%(asctime)s %(threadName)s] %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
    freq = [5,10,15]
    for i in range(0, len(freq)):
    threading.Thread(target=f(freq[i])).start()
```

Este es un ejemplo que estoy intentando. Ejecuto un hilo para cada frecuencia, y llamo a la funcion a la que le paso la frecuencia. Cuando lo ejecuto se queda bloqueada la ejecucion en el primer timer. Creo que es porque el hilo tiene el mismo target siempre, pero ¿como podria hacerlo para solo usar una funcion que me llame a caad timer? Van a ser unas cuantas ejecuciones y crear una funcion para cada hilo es inviable.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No. Tu problema es que *target* tiene que ser una función, y no una **llamada a función**.

```
freq = [5,10,15]
for i in range(0, len(freq)):
    t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(freq[i],,)).start()
```

A los parámetros los vas a recibir, en este caso, como una *tupla* que contiene los valores que necesites pasar a la función que se va a ejecutar en el *thread* correspondiente.

Comment: el uso de range(len(...)) es innecesario, usa lo siguiente `for f in freq:
    threading.Thread(target=f, args=(f,)).start()`

Comment: Muchas gracias por su comentario. Mañana mismo lo probare a ver que tal.